# Why Java Font add a java icon in the Dock of macOs?

Tags: java, macos, java-font

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Font arial = Font.getFont(ImmutableMap.of(TextAttribute.FAMILY, "Arial"));
    System.out.println(arial);
}
```

Having this little program, when executing it on my Mac, it runs (I think) another java process which appears on the Dock (see image below). This icon disappears as soon as the main method ends.

[image]

Anyone have an idea why this happens and how to get rid of it ?

**NB**: The origin of this question is java POI `HSSFSheet` class. I'm generating some `xls` files in a web application and when I call `HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn` the icon appears in the Dock (nothing happens when a don't call `autoSizeColumn`). When I followed this issue I found that the icon appears when `POI` calls `Font.getFont`.

**Environment**:
macOS Catalina: 10.15.4
java version "1.8.0_112"

Comment: Isn't that the java vm process running your program?

Comment: That's simply Java running your program. If you remove the Font creating you will still see it.

Comment: Maybe that's just a timing issue (i.e. it takes some time to get the font info).  What about if you replace it with a `for` loop with 10,000 iterations?

Answer (score 1):

It happens momentarily because of the following classes:

```
java.awt.Font;
java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
```

In short, it will happen with any code using AWT or Swing libraries.

Comment: huum, I see, do you know how to disable this ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'll post an update if I find a way to disable it.

Comment: ok, thank you, another thing: the process behind the icon is the same as the program or another one ?

Comment: This is the standard icon of Java which also matches with the `Java Control Panel` icon in the `System Preferences`.